# Need a JQuery .hover() fixed and stop doing a loop

Tags: jquery, hover

Well have an issue using JQuery hover. Look this is what I want to do, I want to be able to mouseover a div and hide the background image and display a new div over it (I have the div that I want to appear as an absolute so there is no issue), I could get the div to hide but cannot get to get it back whenmouseleve, here is the code I have

```
$('.div_to_hide').hover(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.stop().fadeTo('slow', 0.5, function(){
        $('.div_to_appear').fadeIn('slow');
    });
}, function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.stop().fadeTo('slow', 1.0, function(){
        $('.div_to_appear').fadeOut('fast');
    });
});
```

Hope someone can help me with this situation. It keeps making me a loop going in and out constantly :(

Thanks apreciate your help as used to

Answer (score 0):

The DIV you are showing is probably laying above the hiding DIV, triggering a mouseleave event that creates an event loop. Try adding the hover event to the parent element instead of the DIV you are actually hiding.

Comment: David ur right, thanks man, apreciate your help, it was very veru helpful, thanks again, take care!!